# Some update is causing shell scripts to fail which works fine when ran directly from powershell

Tags: bash, shell, windows, powershell

The call

```
instaloader --post-filter="likes > 16720 and not is_video and date_utc >= datetime(2021, 5, 
29)" --no-profile-pic --no-videos --count=12 cristiano
```

works fine.

But put the same code in `test.sh` and then run it from powershell like this

```
sh .\test.sh
```

or

```
sh ./test.sh
```

or

```
sh test.sh
```

I get error like this

```
usage: 

instaloader [--comments] [--geotags]
            [--stories] [--highlights] [--tagged] [--igtv]
            [--login YOUR-USERNAME] [--fast-update]
            profile | "#hashtag" | %location_id | :stories | :feed | :saved
instaloader --help

instaloader: error: unrecognized arguments: cristiano
```

In case you want to test it out firsthand just install `instaloader` with `pip install instaloader==4.7.1`

PS: The same script used to work fine from `.sh`-files as well few days back, maybe some update to my bash/powershell/windows10 is causing the issue. The issue I guess is in its ability to escape spaces within quotes.

I am on bash 4.4. And no WSL is being used.

**Edit:**

I modified my script with a temporary hack to make it work until this question is resolved. What I did is run the command using python, now my `test.sh` looks like this

```
FILTER="likes > 16720 and not is_video and date_utc >= datetime(2021, 5,  29)"
CMD="instaloader --post-filter=\""$FILTER"\" --no-profile-pic --no-videos --count=12 cristiano"
echo "import os" > test.py
echo "os.system('"$CMD"')" >> test.py
python test.py
```

Call from python works fine. Guys this hack works fine, no problems here. Since @roaima wanted to see the working python code I added it here, it's not much of singnificance to the question here. So to avoid being confused don't look at this edit part, just focus on main question above.

Comment: I've cleaned up the comment string, since the updates have gone into the question. The only advice I have at this point is along the lines of roaima's answer -- that your path is misleading you into calling a different program than you intend. I have not duplicated your environment, so that's the best I can do right now.

Comment: I'll add one more thought on the most recent edit: `echo $env:path` may work in powershell, but it's not doing the same thing in `sh` -- it's expanding the empty `$env` variable and then appending `:path`. You can't expect `sh` to execute powershell code!

Comment: As I said calling Python script is a temporary hack, not my desired path at all. I dont intend to migrate to python.  Thats why I didnt even want it to be mentioned as a part of the question in the first place.